# Getting NaN height error in ivy videojs for ember-cli

Tags: ember-cli, video.js

I have a video set like in example:
autoresize=true naturalWidth=1280 naturalHeight=720
which is actual size but getting the error below.
Even if I take the size off and leave at autoresize=true still get an error.

VIDEOJS: ERROR: Improper value "NaN" supplied for for height

Can anyone help?

Comment: can you please show your full code for initializing the video?